# File Not Found in batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have written a script for removing drive letter of System drive windows

```
cd /d C:\
powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force

@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr System') do (
    (
        echo select volume %%a
        REM echo remove
    ) | diskpart
)
```

Above is my script but something is wrong with it it works fine but shows `File Not Found` error output is below and exited i want to write some commands after this code in same script but it dont work
C:>script.bat

```
C:\>cd /d C:\

C:\>powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
File Not Found

C:\>
```

Comment: You can't write to the root of the C: drive unless you run the batch file with elevated privileges.  Not sure what you are trying to do with that powershell command.  It will have no affect on your batch file.

Comment: maybe a non-destructive example would be better for people who want to reproduce your issue.

Comment: diskpart needs in every case elevation, but you should take a look at `help diskpart` your strange mixing of batch and powershell won't work. You'll need to write  a diskpart script file (eventually on the fly) and hand over that file as an arg to diskpart.

Comment: @LotPings Piping a list of commands into `diskpart` works just fine. I fail to see a non-malicious purpose for removing the drive letter from the system drive, though.

Comment: I removed `echo remove` and ran this and it worked exactly as expected.  Is this your full bat file?